# Gson with RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory and GraphAdapterBuilder

Tags: java, gson

It seems that Gson can't handle POJO's that has recursive reference, and can be of some sub type that is determined at runtime, i'm using GraphAdapterBuilder to handle recursion, and RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory to handle sub types, when used separately serialization and deserialization works, but when combining both, desarialization fails, is there a solution for that without changing my POJO?

Comment: Can you post what your model and TypeAdapter Factory look like, and what the error is?

Comment: A reproducible, simple test case would be 